# Maximize fence post distance for wooden fence?

Tags: wood, fence, metal, steel

We are putting a new wooden fence around our yard. We would like to run it quite close to an existing mature tree, but putting a post too close to the tree will seriously jeopardize its health. Our landscaper says he will put the posts no more than 6 feet apart due to wind in our area.

I am wondering if there is a technique using metal or steel posts instead of 4x4 wood that would let us get a 12-15 foot segment with metal posts on either side and maybe metal header, footer too.  Is such a thing possible and would it likely work?

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: Located in Colorado (Denver area).

Answer (score 1):

Since your landscaper is concerned with wind, I am going to assume you are putting in a privacy fence. In that case, the height could dictate the spacing, if you are willing to put in a lower fence then you could increase post spacing, but 8ft spacing is typical. Also, the lower your fence the less deep the holes would need to be.

Another thing to consider is installation method, if professionals are installing your fence, then they may use an auger to drill the holes, which may damage your tree. However if they are truly professionals, then for the 2 posts closest to the tree, they could use a manual post hole digger, and dig as narrow a hole possible to minimize effect on the tree.

Lastly, if you were to consider another fence type such as a picket fence with narrow pickets, then you could minimize wind loading and increase post spacing.